# paragraphed footnote style with bigfoot

Tags: footnotes, paragraphs, bigfoot

I need paragraphed footnotes precisely as `manyfoot` offers them, but also some of `bigfoot`'s other features (mainly "natural" order of the notes). 
As `bigfoot` is described as "a drop-in replacement of the `manyfoot` package" I suppose it should somehow be possible to switch off the advanced heuristics for the layout of the paragraphed notes, shouldn't it?

I imagine that some parameter/penalty could be set to a very high value that would make `bigfoot` never to fall back to beginning the new note in a new line -- I just couldn't figure out which one.

How could I make `bigfoot`'s layout in this example look as `manyfoot`'s?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[para*]{manyfoot}
%\usepackage[para*]{bigfoot}
 \DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit \footnoteA{sed pharetra amet enim}. Suspendisse id velit vitae ligula volutpat condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero.\footnoteA{Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien.} Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper,\footnoteA{lectus nunc ullamcorperorci} fermentum \footnoteA{bibendum  enim nibh eget} ipsum.\footnoteA{Donec porttitor ligula eu dolor.} Maecenas vitae nulla consequat libero cursus venenatis. Nam magna enim, accumsan eu, blandit sed, blandit a, eros.

\end{document}
```

---

And -- as long as we are waiting for the complete documentation -- has anybody compiled a comprehensive list of all of `bigfoot`'s settings?

Comment: `bigfoot.sty` only mentions 'para', 'para*', 'ruled', and 'verbose'.  However, you request is a very reasonable one.  I would contact the package author and see if this could be added as a standard option.

Comment: To get a package documentation just pdflatex the bigfoot.dtx. With the unmodified version you just get three pages of them which is known by the most of us. If you remove the `\StopEventually{}` on line 143 you get a 55 pages pdf of the bigfoot docu in which the code is explained in a usual way of mixed comments, commands and code.

Comment: @Florian: I want to achieve the same thing (to have _all_ footnotes in-paragraph with bigfoot) and I asked David Kastrup, the package's author, about it some time ago but haven't got an answer so far. If you've made any progress on this, you might want to share it.

Comment: Are you referring to how it places short notes on a new lines, instead of in a paragraph? See the macro on line 936, in particular, lines 943-948. These seem to control the line breaking, such that if the line is too short, footnotes are put on a new line.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. That might very well be the relevant code in this matter. Unfortunately, my knowledge of TeX is not good enough to make any sense or use of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like

```
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}
\expandafter\def\csname @makefnbreak\endcsname{\unskip\linebreak[0]\quad}
```

Answer (score 3):

"Natural order of the notes" does not require `bigfoot`.  That functionality is separately provided by the [`perpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/perpage) package.