# Indentation problem with the 'para' option of bigfoot

Tags: footnotes, indentation, bigfoot

Continuing the questions concerning the layout of footnotes for a critical edition, I am reporting the last issue I am facing. I am using the `para` option of the `bigfoot` package to typeset the footnotes. The thing is that this option doesn't work as I would wish. 
I have encountered a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36931/paragraphed-footnote-style-with-bigfoot) that does not force a linebreak when a note does not completely fit in a line:

```
\expandafter\def\csname @makefnbreak\endcsname{\unskip\linebreak[0]\quad}
```

But I still have the case showing in the image below. When a note starts from a new line (because the previous is already full), it is printed indented. This indentation is unwanted.

[image: the problem]

The second red circle in the image shows the desired behaviour. The first red circle points the actual problem. I supply a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[para]{bigfoot}
\def\extrafootnoterule{\defaultfootnoterule}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}
\def \mylinespacing {1.05}
\expandafter\def\csname @makefnbreak\endcsname{\unskip\linebreak[0]\quad}

\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{}

\newcommand{\foota}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\linespread{\mylinespacing}%
\footnoteA{\textbf{\arabic{poemline}} #1}
\endgroup}
\newcommand{\footb}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\linespread{\mylinespacing}%
\footnoteB{\textbf{\arabic{poemline}} #1}
\endgroup}
\newcommand{\footheirm}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\linespread{\mylinespacing}%
\footnoteA+{#1}
\endgroup}

\hyphenpenalty = 10000
\exhyphenpenalty = 10000

\begin{document}
\verselinenumbersleft
\settowidth{\versewidth}{ααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααα}

\chapter*{CANON I}
\poemlines{5}

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]

\vin ᾠδὴ . \textit{Θαυμαστὸς ἐνδόξως ποιῶν τέρατα}\footheirm{heirm. α΄ EE 76, n. 108, Andreae}

\vin Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
τὸν νοῦν τὸν ἄϋλον,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τῶν θεωριῶν\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὴν σάλπιγγα τὴν θείαν,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην}\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὸ στόμα τῆς σοφίας,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὸν μέγαν θεολόγον\\*
θείοις ὕμνοις ἀνευφημήσωμεν.\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\!

\vin Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
τὸν νοῦν τὸν ἄϋλον,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τῶν \footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}θεωριῶν\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὴν σάλπιγγα τὴν θείαν,\\
τὸ στόμα τῆς σοφίας,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὸν μέγαν θεολόγον\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
θείοις ὕμνοις ἀνευφημήσωμεν.\\!

\vin Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν,\\*
τὸν νοῦν τὸν ἄϋλον,\\
τῶν θεωριῶν \footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὴν σάλπιγγα τὴν θείαν,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὸ στόμα τῆς σοφίας,\\
τὸν μέγαν θεολόγον\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
θείοις ὕμνοις ἀνευφημήσωμεν.\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\!

\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`bigfoot` does not really do more than use the current footnote style, with some reinterpretation when formatting footnotes in a horizontal block.

It is probably easiest to use a footnote restyling package like

```
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
```

before loading `bigfoot`.  Using that makes quite obvious that your `\foota` and `\footb` commands would do well to use a non-breakable space `~` instead of  before `#1`.

Comment: Can you show the usage with a MWE, please?  Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @user64858, I added the package with the option you suggested and the indentation completely disappeared from all the footnote lines. However, this is not quite what I want.  http://i.imgur.com/HxKFMvv.png The red lines indicate the beginning of the paragraphs of the footnotes, where indentation is crucial!

Answer (score 1):

This solution may or may not be acceptable to you.  What it does is prevent a footnote from finishing at the end-of-line (by forcing a premature wrap).  It does this by modifying `\footnoteA` as follows

```
\footnoteA{\textbf{\arabic{poemline}} #1\makebox[\mykern]{}%
           \setbox0=\hbox{\ }\ \kern-\wd0\kern-\mykern}
```

What this redefinition accomplishes is to lay an empty `\mykern`-width box at the end of the footnote, add a space, and then kern leftward the space plus `\mykern`.  Thus any footnote within `\mykern` distance from the end of line will wrap.  The idea is to prevent any footnote after the first from beginning at the start of a line.

The value of `\mykern` may require tuning to achieve the best result.  I have it currently set to 40pt.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[para]{bigfoot}
\def\extrafootnoterule{\defaultfootnoterule}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}
\def \mylinespacing {1.05}
\newlength\mykern
\setlength\mykern{40pt}%MUST BE LARGE ENOUGH TO FORCE AT-END LINE TO LINEBREAK
\expandafter\def\csname @makefnbreak\endcsname{\unskip\linebreak[0]\quad}

\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{}

\newcommand{\foota}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\linespread{\mylinespacing}%
\footnoteA{\textbf{\arabic{poemline}} #1\makebox[\mykern]{}%
           \setbox0=\hbox{\ }\ \kern-\wd0\kern-\mykern}
\endgroup%
}
\newcommand{\footb}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\linespread{\mylinespacing}%
\footnoteB{\textbf{\arabic{poemline}} #1}
\endgroup}
\newcommand{\footheirm}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\linespread{\mylinespacing}%
\footnoteA+{#1}
\endgroup}

\hyphenpenalty = 10000
\exhyphenpenalty = 10000

\begin{document}
\verselinenumbersleft
\settowidth{\versewidth}{ααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααα}

\chapter*{CANON I}
\poemlines{5}

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]

\vin ᾠδὴ . \textit{Θαυμαστὸς ἐνδόξως ποιῶν τέρατα}\footheirm{heirm. α΄ EE 76, n. 108, Andreae}

\vin Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
τὸν νοῦν τὸν ἄϋλον,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τῶν θεωριῶν\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὴν σάλπιγγα τὴν θείαν,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην}\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὸ στόμα τῆς σοφίας,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὸν μέγαν θεολόγον\\*
θείοις ὕμνοις ἀνευφημήσωμεν.\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\!

\vin Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
τὸν νοῦν τὸν ἄϋλον,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τῶν \footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}θεωριῶν\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὴν σάλπιγγα τὴν θείαν,\\
τὸ στόμα τῆς σοφίας,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὸν μέγαν θεολόγον\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
θείοις ὕμνοις ἀνευφημήσωμεν.\\!

\vin Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν,\\*
τὸν νοῦν τὸν ἄϋλον,\\
τῶν θεωριῶν \footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὴν σάλπιγγα τὴν θείαν,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὸ στόμα τῆς σοφίας,\\
τὸν μέγαν θεολόγον\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
θείοις ὕμνοις ἀνευφημήσωμεν.\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\!

\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is a nice idea and it seems to work fine, even if it is just a way to "avoid" the problem of the indentation. Surely useful and I may finally implement this logic to my edition, but I will leave the question open for now.